# File name doesnt read in the PHPcurl api

Tags: php-curl

I have a api integrated using phpcurl.Where there is upload file functionality .When using the PHP code to call a Webservices with the parameters.The file name doesnt get added

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://Xx.XXX.XXX.XX/demo/v1/uploadScannedDocs",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"preQualify\"\r\n\r\n" . $checkbox1 . "\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"demographicPid\"\r\n\r\n" . $patient_id . "\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"barcode\"\r\n\r\n" . $barcode . "\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"consentDate\"\r\n\r\n" . $consent_date . "\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"CSCDB_0523_TableDef.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: false\r\n\r\n\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"hipa\"; filename=\"CSCDB_0523_TableDef.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: false\r\n\r\n\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"medrioId\"\r\n\r\n" . $id . "\r\n-----011000010111000001101001--",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001",
    "deviceid: 123",
    "postman-token: 4655c7e4-f473-7383-6fd1-ef07ded61caf",
    "token: 1234"
)));
```

Comment: Most likely what you are sending as POSTFIELDS is not correct. Where does that string come from? Did you assemble it yourself? That is something you rather shouldn’t be doing. The proper way to upload files using PHP cURL is http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php

Comment: Even when i use this $file_name      = basename($_FILES["document"]["name"]);
$file_name_hipa = basename($_FILES["document_hipa"]["name"]);

Comment: @CBroe :Can u suggest me how to go about to writing the POSTFIELDS with file upload along with multiple  parameters

Comment: Manual has examples in the user comments.

Comment: when i post the paramters in the body with form-data and check the generate code also the filename is shown as [object object] in postman

Comment: `[object object]` is usually what you get in JavaScript, if you try and use an object in a string context. (Is there any JS involved? If so, please update your question with the relevant parts.) Most of the time this happens when you try and put an object into a string, whereas you should really be using one of the properties of that object.